# Issue in communicating socket and VMware-Workstation stub

Tags: java, sockets, stub, vmware-workstation

I am implementing a socket in Java for communicating with VMware-Workstation (Version: 8.0.0 build-471780).

I create the socket with: `Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",8832);`, since I'm running the virtual machine locally and 8832 is the port that VMware listens for debugging by defalut.
The connection is not being refused or throwing any kind of exceptions.
However, I'm in trouble to establish a communication between my process and the VMware stub.

These methods are not effectively sending or receiving anything from the stub:

```
public void sendStr(String str) throws IOException {
        out.write(str.getBytes());
}
public String getStr() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {//blocking call
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[40];
    in.read(byteArray);
    return new String(byteArray);
}
```

The second method never ends, since it's a blocking call.

When i terminate the Java process, my virtual machine notices the lost of debugger connection, so I'm able to say that the connection was succesfully made.

Can someone help me here? I don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try running the program in the same system, without using the Virtual Machine?

Its not save to ignore the return value of `read` as it may not read the full length. Your application could hang if you expect to receive the same number of "messages" as you send.  This is because a Socket is a stream of bytes and you can have any number of sent strings combine or split.

A safer approach is to use DataOutput/InputStreams

```
final DataOutputStream out = 

public void sendStr(String str) throws IOException {
    out.writeUTF(str);
}

final DataInputStream in = 

public String getStr() throws IOException {//blocking call
    return in.readUTF(); // will return exactly on string.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't run the program outside the Virtual Machine. I've tried the way you said, but it hangs at the 'getStr()' method. It is probably happenning something similar at the 'sendStr()', but only the 'getStr()' is blocking, so I hangs just there.

Comment: Can you run inside the Virtual machine then? If the getStr hangs its because the sender isn't sending.  I would add a log message before and after the writeUTF() to see if it is sending.

Comment: You're right, it isn't sending also! The problem does not seem to be with the connection, since the vmware.log file says: "Debug stub remote connection accepted"

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was not about sockets or anything like that. I just wasn't aware of some particularities from the protocol. Anyway, thanks for your help.